# Change local variable inside method, when the method is executed the variable is not changed

Tags: java, android, logcat

I'm working on an android app. I have this form, when the button is clicked it execute a method called insertData(). Inside this function I change a local variable called "address" with another function getAddress().

Inside the function getAddress the local variable "address" is changed successfully. But when we enter the function insertData(), the variable "address" still contains the old data in this case "Location Unknown".

What am I not seeing here?

**insertData()**

```
public String address = "Location unknown";

public boolean insertData(String title, String description, String image, Double longitude, Double latitude, String date) {
    String location = Double.toString(longitude) + "," + Double.toString(latitude);
    getAddress(location);
    Log.d("TAG2", address); // Still "Location unknown"
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, description);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, image);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, longitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, latitude);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, date);
    contentValues.put(COL_8, address);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

**getAddress()**

```
    public void getAddress(String coordination) {

    String token = "{removed for a reason haha}";
    String url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + coordination + ".json?access_token=" + token;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                String data = response.body().string();
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

                try {
                    JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(data);
                    JsonArray arr = obj.getAsJsonArray("features");
                    JsonObject objj = arr.get(2).getAsJsonObject();
                    String place = objj.get("place_name").getAsString();
                        address = place;
                        Log.d("TAG", address); // Gives an address
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Logcat Debugger**

```
2019-06-15 20:12:58.968 31465-31465/com.example.triptracker D/TAG2: Location unkown
2019-06-15 20:12:59.269 31465-31569/com.example.triptracker D/TAG: Mountain View, California, United States
```

I cannot change the onResponse() method to return String. I don't know why, but it is a read only method.

**getAddress {changed}**

```
    public void getAddress(String coordination) {

    String token = "{empty}";
    String url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + coordination + ".json?access_token=" + token;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        String data = response.body().string();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(data);
        JsonArray arr = obj.getAsJsonArray("features");
        JsonObject objj = arr.get(2).getAsJsonObject();
        String place = objj.get("place_name").getAsString();
        address = place;
        Log.d("TAG", address);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAddress()` does its work asynchronously. By the time `getAddress()` returns, your HTTP request will not be complete, and so `address` will not have changed yet.

Since `insertData()` is doing disk I/O, you should be calling `insertData()` on its own background thread, so you do not freeze the UI while the disk I/O is going on. If that is the case, then you can use OkHttp synchronously, using `execute()` instead of `enqueue()`. That will allow you to have `getAddress()` return the address, so you can insert it into your database.

Comment: Aah I know what you mean, I'm familiar with this but then with Node.js. Uhm anyway, when I am changing the enqueue() to execute(), I'm getting this error: error: method execute in interface Call cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: <anonymous Callback>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @StevenSoekha: `execute()` does not take a `Callback`. It returns your `Response` object or throws an exception. See [this recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/RECIPES.md#synchronous-get).

Comment: Okay, I've changed it, but it still doesn't work in the app. Do you think you can maybe have a look? I will update this post and insert the new getAddress() somewhere below.

Comment: @StevenSoekha: I don't know what "doesn't work in the app" means. Check Logcat for exceptions, step through your code in the debugger, etc.

Comment: The location still outputs "Location unknown"

Comment: @StevenSoekha: Check your Logcat for exceptions and/or step through your code in the debugger. If your `getAddress()` method has a problem, it will print the stack trace to Logcat. My guess is that you are getting an exception somewhere. For example, if you are calling `getAddress()` on the main application thread, you will get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Log.d("TAG", address); now doesn't even execute. In logcat it doesn't pop up.

Comment: Wow you are right. I'm getting this in the debugger:

Comment: 2019-06-15 21:28:20.728 1105-1105/com.example.triptracker W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @StevenSoekha: I covered this in the second paragraph of my answer. You should be calling `insertData()` (and, from there, `getAddress()`) on a background thread.